OAuth2 google drive AccesToken refresh using Google Credential Manager + AuthorizationClient
My question: How can I request a OAuth2 credential object to access the Google Drive API, that is automatically refresh after the accessToken is expired?
What I did:
I followed the latest suggestions from Google, how to access the Google Drive API on Android by first doing an authentication via Credential Manager and then an authorization via Google Indentiy:
https://developers.google.com/identity/android-credential-manager
https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android
Also here I found help:
How to authenticate Google Sign In using CredentialManager and authorize to Google Drive API in Android?
My current code for the authentication is the following (for using Credential Manager there are many good code examples easy to find by Google):
    private fun authorizeGoogleDrive() {
        val requestedScopes = listOf(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_READONLY))
        val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder()
            .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
            .build()
        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this)
            .authorize(authorizationRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
                if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
                    val pendingIntent = authorizationResult.pendingIntent
                    try {
                        val intentSenderRequest = pendingIntent?.let { IntentSenderRequest.Builder(it.intentSender).build() }
                        intentSenderRequest?.let { authorizeGoogleDriveResultReceiver.launch(intentSenderRequest) }
                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        Log.e(LOG, "SignInActivity/authorizeGoogleDrive Couldn't start Authorization UI: " + e.localizedMessage)
                    }
                } else {
                
                  buildDriveService(authorizationResult)
                  
                }
            }
    }

    private val authorizeGoogleDriveResultReceiver = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val authorizationResult: AuthorizationResult = Identity.getAuthorizationClient(
                this
            ).getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(result.data)

            buildDriveService(authorizationResult)

        } else {
            Log.e(LOG, "SignInActivity/authorizeGoogleDriveResultReceiver result.resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK")
        }
    }
    
    
    fun buildDriveService(authorizationResult: AuthorizationResult) {
        val accessToken = AccessToken(authorizationResult.accessToken, Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600 * 1000))
        val credential = GoogleCredentials.create(accessToken)
        driveService = Drive.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            HttpCredentialsAdapter(credential)
        )
            .setApplicationName(app_name)
            .build()

    }

The access worked well for a while (60 minutes), but then I got the following exception using my driveService Object:

OAuth2Credentials instance does not support refreshing the access
token. An instance with a new access token should be used, or a
derived type that supports refreshing.

And what is really strange: when I restart my app, I always get the same access token, regardless that I am calling Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this).authorize(authorizationRequest) again.
According to the documentation of com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials with extends OAuth2Credentials, refreshing access tokens is not supported.
https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-auth-library/latest/com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials
I tried to switch from GoogleCredentials to com.google.auth.oauth2.UserCredentials, hoping that this Class supports automatic token refreshing.
But I could not yet successfully use its Builder, always getting a null pointer exception. Also I need a refresh Token calling this Builder:
    val userCredentials = UserCredentials.newBuilder()
        .setClientId(app_name)
        .setAccessToken(accessToken)
        .setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
        .build()

But I don't have a refreshToken. In authorizationResult object I get via Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this).authorize(authorizationRequest), there is only a filed accessToken, but no refreshToken.
What can I do?

I encountered the same issue, and it turned out to be caused by an incorrect date setting on the device. After syncing the time and date to the correct values, everything worked fine again. It seems the error handling for this scenario could be improved, as the actual cause wasn’t clearly indicated.

thank you for your response. In the meanwhile I could solve my problems and you are right, the time in my emulator was not set correctly.
But this was not the main reason for the refresh issue.

I addded "requestOfflineAccess" to the AuthorizationRequest to get a "serverAuthCode"

val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder()
    .requestOfflineAccess(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id), true)
    .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
    .build()

The AuthorizationResult.accessToken I do not use anymore. Instead I use the accessToken I get in the next step, that differs from the included accessToken in the AuthorizationResult.

With the "serverAuthCode" I requested an access/refresh Token. Here I needed to setup a "clientSecret" in the Google Cloud console to get it working.

val tokenResponse = GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
    GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
    GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    getString(R.string.default_web_client_id),
    getString(R.string.clientSecret),
    authorizationResult.serverAuthCode,
    getString(R.string.redirectUri)
).execute()
tokenResponse?.let {
    val accessToken = AccessToken(it.accessToken, Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + it.expiresInSeconds * 1000))
    val refreshToken = it.refreshToken

}


Now I was able the use the "UserCredential" Class that supports token refresh different to "OAuth2Credentials", that does not support refreshing.

var userCredentials = UserCredentials.newBuilder()
    .setClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
    .setClientSecret(getString(R.string.clientSecret))
    .setAccessToken(accessToken)
    .setRefreshToken(refreshToken)
    .build()
userCredentials?.let {
    driveService = Drive.Builder(
        GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
        GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
        HttpCredentialsAdapter(it)
    )
        .setApplicationName(getString(R.string.applicationName))
        .build()
}


before usind the driveService, I always call:

userCredentials?.refreshIfExpired()

The documentation from Google is very poor. Especially I am still not 100% sure, if the driveService object takes into account the token changes of the userCrediatials object after its creation and if the object needs be rebuilt or not.
More precise, I wonder if the HttpCredentialsAdapter(userCredentials) is called by reference or by value.
If anybody can tell me a source of good documentation or code examples I would be happy. Everything I find on Google ressources was outdated.
